# App crashing when deleting item from NSMutableArray, but only when certain conditions are met

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, sigabrt

I have an app, written in `Objective-C`, that needs to display a `UITable` of numbers. The list of numbers is taken from an `NSMutableArray` whose information is taken from a .plist file. Normally, all is fine.

However, the app includes settings to organize the numbers in specific ways. The default setting just organizes them in alphabetical order. The next organizes them in reverse to the default. Those two settings are fine. The problem arises when one selects the setting that organizes the table by splitting the odd numbers and the even numbers. This is the code that splits them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [tempGeneralSorterArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *tempHouseNumber = [[tempGeneralSorterArray objectAtIndex:i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:letters];
    int tempHouseNumberValue = [tempHouseNumber intValue];

    if (tempHouseNumberValue % 2 == 0) //% is the modulo operator, shows what's left after a division
    {
        //even
        [tempEvenSorterArray addObject:[tempGeneralSorterArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [tempEvenSorterArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    }
    else
    {
        //odd
        [tempOddSorterArray addObject:[tempGeneralSorterArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [tempOddSorterArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    }
}
```

After this, the app combines the two arrays (tempOddSorterArray and tempEvenSorterArray) in different ways depending on the setting chosen, but in general like this:

```
customerArray = [tempOddSorterArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tempEvenSorterArray];
```

The table displays mostly fine, but when I try to delete a cell, I get an error. It crashes at this line:

```
[customerArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I get this in the debugger:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae62410f30'
```

Any help would be appreciated, and I'll gladly give more info or code if needed.

Also, all arrays used here are NSMutableArrays.

Comment: _Also, all arrays used here are NSMutableArrays._  This is false.  At least one is immutable, as can be seen from the exception: `__NSArrayI`.

Comment: @Avi I declared all three of my used arrays (customerArray, tempEvenSorterArray and tempOddSorterArray) in my .h file as NSMutableArrays... Is it possible for it to change to a regular one if I did something wrong later on?

Comment: The declared type of a variable only tells the compiler what you think it is.  It has little impact on what the type actually _is_.  This is even more true for objects, and then again more true for class clusters and subclasses, such as `NSArray` and relatives.

Comment: @Avi is there a way I can find out what each of my arrays really are?

Comment: You know `customerArray` is immutable.  You haven't posted any code which references it, so there's no way to help you figure out which method is giving you an immutable array.

Comment: By any chance, do you call `copy` on any of your arrays?  `copy` on `NSMutableArray` gives an `NSArray`.  You have to call `mutableCopy` if you want a mutable copy.

Comment: I did not call copy on any arrays. ``customerArray`` gets initiated by ``customerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[rootDict allKeys]];`` and then it either just gets sorted with the default and reversed default settings (works fine), or gets overwritten by some version of ``customerArray = [tempEvenSorterArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tempOddSorterArray];`` (does not work fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though customerArray  has been declared as mutable, [tempOddSorterArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tempEvenSorterArray] return an immutable array. Try modifying it like [[tempOddSorterArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tempEvenSorterArray]mutableCopy]; Let me know if it wroks. :)

Comment: It actually worked, thank you so much! Thanks a lot as well to @avi who helped me find and correct another unrelated issue. Learned a lot from both of you. However, I'm not sure why it was returning an immutable array from a mutable one. Is there a reason that could happen?

Comment: Welcome :) . "arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray" . doesn't modify the array on which it is called but returns a new array. and also the method name itself says, return me a new array (not mutable array) by adding two arrays.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought it would just modify it, I didn't think it would completely replace it. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Calling `[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]` is more efficient as it doesn't create another array object.  Your suggestion is poor for performance.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out that

```
 customerArray = [tempOddSorterArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tempEvenSorterArray];
```

returns a new NSArray instance but not an NSMutableArray instance. Whereas you need an NSMutableArray type of instance to call removeObject method on it. 
You can achieve this by calling the method mutableCopy after you receive an NSArray. This is how you can do it:

```
 customerArray = [[tempOddSorterArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:tempEvenSorterArray] mutableCopy];

 [customerArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You could also try the following, as @Droppy claims it to be more efficient approach,

```
NSMutableArray * customerArray; 
[customerArray addObjectsFromArray: tempEvenSorterArray];
```

Comment: Use `[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:]` as it's more efficient.

Comment: @Droppy: okay, but for your knowledge, addObjectsFromArray: is not a class method. It's an instance method. Thus, it should be done this way: NSMutableArray * customerArray; [customArray addObjectsFromArray: tempEvenSorterArray];